# How to perform auto increament in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am inserting values into mysql database my using following statement

```
string regInset =
  "INSERT INTO Fn_Registration VALUES ('" + txtFirstName.Text + "', '" + txtLastName.Text + "', " + " '" + 
   txtEmailId.Text + "', " + " '" + txtPassword.Text + "', " + " '" + 
   txtPanNumber.Text + "', " + " '" + txtAddress1.Text + "', " + " '" + 
   txtAddress2.Text + "', " + " '" + txtFaxNo.Text + "'," + " '" + 
   txtFirmName.Text + "', " + " '" + txtPhoneNumber.Text + "', " + " '" + 
   txtTinNumber.Text + "',  " + " '"+txtFinancialYearStart.Text+"','"+
   txtFinancialYearEnd.Text+"','" + txtAccountsStart.Text + "', " + " '" + 
   txtAccountsEnd.Text + "','" + cbbVat.Text + "', " + " '" + 
   cbbstates.Text + "', " + " '" + txtCity.Text +"','"+
   txtCircle.Text+"','"+txtDivision.Text+ "', '" + 
   txtBankName.Text + "', '" + txtAccountNumber.Text + "', " + " '" + 
   txtIFSCCode.Text + "', " + " '" + txtBN1.Text + "', " + " '" + 
   txtAC1.Text + "', " + " '" + txtIFSC1.Text + "', " + " '" + 
   txtBN2.Text + "', " + " '" + txtAC2.Text + "', " + " '" + 
   txtIFSC2.Text + "', " + " '" + DateTime.Now + "')";
```

I want to perform auto increament on a particular column say "ID" , but i want to do it in mysql wizard at the table settings , but not with code. Is it possible?
      I have tick marked the auto increament option in mysql table wizard but no use. Increament is not done...

Comment: You have to supply `NULL` for the `ID` column in your `INSERT` statement, or provide a list of columns to fill in and leave the `ID` column out of the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you use INT as datatype of your ID it should work fine. Do check what datatype you are using for ID Column.

Comment: Paste the create statement of your table here. I think I can help you out after that.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using **AUTO_INCREMENT**, try this

```
CREATE TABLE Fn_Registration (
     ID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     ---Other columns---
     PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

Comment: You can extract the query by SHOW CREATE TABLE `Fn_Registration`; By this you can get the create query of table and then do the modification as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to insert anything in your `ID` column.

For example:

You have the following columns in your DB: `ID`, `col1`, `col2`, `col3` where `ID` **is** marked to auto incrase.

Your query should look like:

```
INSERT INTO tableName(col1, col2, col3)
VALUES(val1, val2, val3);
```

As you can see the `ID` column is not included in the query, as it is already market to auto incrase itself.